# Un-check and check all for multiple sets of checkbuttons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, checkbox

I have two different sets of checkboxes.

```
// "Broker" Checkboxes
    <label class="container" >Select All
                        <input type="checkbox" id="select-all" checked >
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container" >Avisons
                        <input type="checkbox" id="AvisonCheckbox" checked >
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container" >CBRE
                        <input type="checkbox" id="CBRECheckbox" checked >
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>


//"Tenant" Checkboxes
<div class="tenantSelectAll" >Select All
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tenantSelect-all"  checked/>
                    <label  for="tenantSelect-all"></label>
                </div>
                        
                <div class="round" style="margin-right:30px">WeWork
                    <input type="checkbox" id="WeWorkCheckbox"  checked/>
                    <label  for="WeWorkCheckbox"></label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="Regus" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:13px">Regus
                    <input type="checkbox" id="RegusCheckbox"  checked/>
                    <label  for="RegusCheckbox"></label>
                </div>
```

The issue is that I'm trying to implement select all/un-select all checkbox for each checkbox set listed above.  The following code, works, but it selects/de-selects both "Broker" AND "Tenant" checkboxes.  I want the Select All checkbox from the "Broker" checkboxes to only select/de-select from the "Broker" checkboxes, and have the same be true for the "Tenant" checkboxes.

```
//Implement Select All and Unselect all checkboxes
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
if(this.checked) {
    // Iterate each checkbox
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;                        
    });
} else {
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;                       
    });
}
});
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding a class to the checkbox, or even putting those inputs into separate containers and referencing direct.
This code works for me. Hope it helped.

```js
//Implement Select All and Unselect all checkboxes
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
if(this.checked) {
    // Iterate each checkbox
    $(':checkbox.brokeropt').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;                        
    });
} else {
    $(':checkbox.brokeropt').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;                       
    });
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// "Broker" Checkboxes
    <label class="container" >Select All
                        <input type="checkbox" id="select-all" checked >
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container" >Avisons
                        <input type="checkbox" class="brokeropt" id="AvisonCheckbox" checked >
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container" >CBRE
                        <input type="checkbox" class="brokeropt" id="CBRECheckbox" checked >
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                
                //"Tenant" Checkboxes
<div class="tenantSelectAll" >Select All
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tenantSelect-all"  checked/>
                    <label  for="tenantSelect-all"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="round" style="margin-right:30px">WeWork
                    <input type="checkbox" id="WeWorkCheckbox"  checked/>
                    <label  for="WeWorkCheckbox"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="Regus" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:13px">Regus
                    <input type="checkbox" id="RegusCheckbox"  checked/>
                    <label  for="RegusCheckbox"></label>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try paste the following code : add Broker class for sub checkbox of Broker, and add  Tenant for sub checkbox of Tenant , then in select all event , using class selector .
Holp this helpful for you.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {         
        $('#select-all,#tenantSelect-all').click(function (event) {
            switch (this.id) {
                case "select-all":
                    // check or uncheck by class
                    $(':checkbox.Broker').prop("checked", this.checked);
                    // or you can  check or uncheck by org
                    $('label :checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
                    break;
                case "tenantSelect-all":
                    // check or uncheck by class
                    $(':checkbox.Tenant').prop("checked", this.checked);
                    // or you can  check or uncheck by org
                    $('div :checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
                    break;
            }
        });
     });
</script>
<label class="container" >Select All
    <input type="checkbox" id="select-all" checked >
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container" >Avisons
    <input class="Broker"  type="checkbox" id="AvisonCheckbox" checked >
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container" >CBRE
    <input class="Broker"  type="checkbox" id="CBRECheckbox" checked >
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<div class="tenantSelectAll" >Select All
    <input type="checkbox" id="tenantSelect-all"  checked/>
    <label  for="tenantSelect-all"></label>
</div>

<div class="round" style="margin-right:30px">WeWork
    <input  class="Tenant"   type="checkbox" id="WeWorkCheckbox"  checked/>
    <label  for="WeWorkCheckbox"></label>
</div>

<div class="Regus" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:13px">Regus
    <input class="Tenant"   type="checkbox" id="RegusCheckbox"  checked/>
    <label  for="RegusCheckbox"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with D3

```js
d3.select("#brokerSelect-all")
  .on('click', function () {
    let that = this;
    d3.selectAll(".brokercheck")
      .each(function () { this.checked = that.checked });
  });
d3.select("#tenantSelect-all")
  .on('click', function () {
    let that = this;
    d3.selectAll(".tenantcheck")
      .each(function () { this.checked = that.checked });
  });
```

```html
<p>"Broker" Checkboxes</p>
<label class="container" >Select All
    <input type="checkbox" id="brokerSelect-all" checked >
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container" >Avisons
    <input class="brokercheck" type="checkbox" id="AvisonCheckbox" checked >
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container" >CBRE
    <input class="brokercheck" type="checkbox" id="CBRECheckbox" checked >
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>


<p>"Tenant" Checkboxes</p>
<div class="tenantSelectAll" >Select All
    <input type="checkbox" id="tenantSelect-all"  checked/>
    <label  for="tenantSelect-all"></label>
</div>

<div class="round" style="margin-right:30px">WeWork
    <input class="tenantcheck" type="checkbox" id="WeWorkCheckbox"  checked/>
    <label  for="WeWorkCheckbox"></label>
</div>

<div class="Regus" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:13px">Regus
    <input class="tenantcheck" type="checkbox" id="RegusCheckbox"  checked/>
    <label  for="RegusCheckbox"></label>
</div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```